# Need to scrape glassdoor company reviews

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have tried web scraping of glassdoor company reviews using beautiful soup, selenium, mechanical soup, and gazpacho in all libraries when i ran it from my local i was able to scrape. But the same code when I was trying to run from my AWS ec2 instance i was facing the 403 forbidden error. However my expectation is to run the code from the server. I have two ec2 instance one linux and one is windows in both of them Iam facing a same error

tried this code snippet returns `403 forbidden` error:

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion'

url = "https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/Wells-Fargo-Reviews-E8876.htm"

request = urllib.request.Request(url)
request.add_header('User-Agent', user_agent)

response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

with open('Output_new.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(response.read(), file=f)
```

while running this code I get `403` tried to add more headers

I also tried it using gazpacho libraries get method

here:

```
url = 'https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/Wells-Fargo-Reviews-E8876.htm'
html = get(url)

soup = Soup(html)
print(soup)

with open('Output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(soup, file=f)
```

here also I am facing the same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not use their API instead (if they offer one)? Scraping is always error prone, if not illegal

Answer (score 0):

I found [this method](https://github.com/MatthewChatham/glassdoor-review-scraper) created by Matthew to be very helpful! I had to tweak it a little to get it to work (where you link to the landing page of the company at the top of the main.py function, I replaced it with the landing page of the company's reviews) and then added a line at the bottom to save my results as a CSV.